# AWS Cognito authentication without password for backend server-server call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We have started to explore AWS Cognito for authentication with our applications. Right now, we developed a POC application where user signs up/sign in with a password and obtains the JWT. But from server-server we need to a way to login and obtain the JWT without a password(like a trusted sign in ).But when I explored, I found an article 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/implementing-passwordless-email-authentication-with-amazon-cognito/. But in this article, still there is an otp sent to client. We don't want to interact with the client in server-server communication.Is there any feature that AWS cognito offers for the above requirement.

Comment: This is AWS amplify                                                                                                    https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html

Answer (score 1):

We use a model like the one described in [this](https://lobster1234.github.io/2018/05/31/server-to-server-auth-with-amazon-cognito/) article.